Integrating out spin in 2-electron energy function
I am just starting to learn Quantum Chemistry for my research. I am currently reading Modern Quantum Chemistry by Szabo and I am a little confused by a concept. The two-electron ground state energy is:
$$E_0 = <\psi|H|\psi> =  \sum_a[a|h|a]+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a\sum_b{[aa|bb]-[ab|ba]}$$
where the first term is the one-electron energy and the second two terms consider the excited state with interaction between electrons.
That part makes sense to me. However, I am now finding out about integrating out the spin, so that we just have spatial orbitals left.
As the possible spatial states are a sum of 1/2 (up-spin) spatial orbitals + 1/2 (down-spin) spatial orbitals, the first term above becomes:
$$\sum_a[a|h|a] = 2\sum_a^{N/2}{(\psi_a|h|\psi_a)}$$
And the second two terms become
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_a\sum_b{[aa|bb]-[ab|ba]} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_a^{N/2}\sum_b^{N/2} \left( [aa|bb] -[ab|ba] +[aa|\bar{bb}]-[a\bar{b}|\bar{b}a]+[\bar{aa}|bb]-[\bar{a}b|b\bar{a}]+[\bar{aa}|\bar{bb}]-[\bar{ab}|\bar{ba}]\right) $$
Which are the possible combinations of up and down (letters with the bar) spin orbitals. The "issue" is that $<a|b> = <b|a> = 0$ for opposite spin states, so I thought that a consequences would be that the $\mathbf{bolded}$ terms are zeroed:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_a\sum_b{[aa|bb]-[ab|ba]} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_a^{N/2}\sum_b^{N/2} \left( [aa|bb] -[ab|ba] +[aa|\bar{bb}]-\mathbf{[a\bar{b}|\bar{b}a]}+[\bar{aa}|bb]-\mathbf{[\bar{a}b|b\bar{a}]}+[\bar{aa}|\bar{bb}]-[\bar{ab}|\bar{ba}]\right) $$
However, the textbook reduces that to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_a\sum_b{[aa|bb]-[ab|ba]} = \sum_a^{N/2}\sum_b^{N/2}{2(\psi_a\psi_a|\psi_b\psi_b)-(\psi_a\psi_b|\psi_b\psi_a)}$$
Could anybody help me understand why the terms I bolded are not zero?
Thank you :)

I have trouble with "the second two terms consider the excited state with interaction between electrons." From my understanding these are the Coulomb and exchange integrals, this has nothing to do with excited state or not. These are just the two-electron interactions. Could you clarify what you mean, please. || Not all of us are too familiar with Szabo and Ostlund's notation; I guess a remineder would help things along.

There is that post I wrote 'eons' ago: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/41806 Unfortunately, my browser crashes (probably due to the extreme usage of MathJax). There could be the answer though, I mean if your equipment can load it. *sigh* I'd love to check, but I am limited here.
